# PHP reading XLSX files with spreadsheet-reader: issue with the scale of percentage decimals

Tags: php, excel, scale, percentage, reader

**Issue with the PHP Excel spreadsheet-reader**

When reading XLSX files that contain percentage decimals with a scale of more than 2 digits the reader will always round up the decimal to up to the second digit on the right side of the decimal point.

**Example**

XLSX file contains a cell formatted as percentage with this value:

4.54611%

Then the reader will always return this value:

4.55%

The problem is that I need to read the whole decimal (or rounded to the 5th digits on the right side of the decimal point).